# Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar results in no ActionBar showing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-styles

I created a project with a blank activity (and then wrote code to put in a basic fragment - empty linear layout) in Android Studio but there is no ActionBar showing. Why?

**Device: Emulator (Nexus 5 size), API 19**

The main activity extends `FragmentActivity`.

The Android Studio generated styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

The activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.test" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: @Elltz I added the manifest.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Instead of extending `FragmentActivity`, I need the main class to extend `AppCompatActivity`.

As explained here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

> If you're using the v7 appcompat library, your activity should instead extend ActionBarActivity, which is a subclass of FragmentActivity (for more information, read Adding the Action Bar).

**EDIT**

`ActionBarActivity` [is now deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html). Use `AppCompatActivity` instead.

Comment: I extend my activity from ActionBarActivity and use "Theme.AppCompat.Light" but now it doesn't show app icon on the action bar, only the name of the activity.
If I used "ThemeOverlay.AppCompat", and extend "Activity", it shows the action bar with app icon, but I don't like that theme because I cannot see dark text.